# How to read cookie on Angular2 side (set by the c# server)

Tags: javascript, c#, angular

I can't figure out how the angular code can read the cookie set on the server side.
The code below is taken from GitHub. The function below in written in c# and sets the cookie in Response object by the last line of code.
My question is how do I read this cookie on the Angular2 java script side. Can someone point me to the right direction please?

```
private void setTokenCookie(string token)
{
    var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
    {
        HttpOnly = true,
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7)
    };
    Response.Cookies.Append("refreshToken", token, cookieOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Angular` does not have native support for `Cookies`. You need to use either a built-in library for this available on `NPM` or deal with it simply with `JavaScript` and browser capability.

Option 1:

You can use [angular2-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-cookie)

Option 2:

You can use a method like this (or update it) to meet your need of reading a cookie:

```
readCookies(){
 let name = name + "="; 
 let cookie_array = document.cookie.split(';'),
 for(var i=0;i<cookie_array.length;i++) {
    let cookie=cookie_array[i];
    while(cookie.charAt(0)==' '){
       cookie = cookie.substring(1,cookie.length);
       if(cookie.indexOf(name)==0){
       return cookie.substring(name.length,cookie.length);
      }
   }
 }
}
```

I hope this helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the answer but I am after reading cookie that was returned to me from the server in Response object - not the cookie kept by the browser in document.cookie

Comment: Is cookie returned in Response automatically put in the document.cookie on the client side?